# nginx serving alternate location on 404

Tags: nginx, proxy, configuration, rewrite, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to set up an nginx config as follows: When receiving a request like `/tile/SteveCountryVic/1/2/3.png`:

1. Attempt to pass it through to `http://localhost:5005/1/2/3.png`
2. If that 404s, pass it to another server as `/tile/SteveCountryVic/1/2/3.png`

Here's my config which isn't quite working:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;   error_log  /tmp/nginx.error.log notice;
   access_log   /tmp/nginx.access.log;
   location /tile/SteveCountryVic/ {
        rewrite_log on;        
        #rewrite ^.*/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+).*$ /$1/$2/$3.png break;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = @dynamiccycletour;        
        #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5005;
        proxy_redirect /tile/SteveCountryVic/ http://localhost:5005/;

   location @dynamiccycletour {
        rewrite_log on;
        #rewrite ^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+).*$ /tile/SteveCountryVic/$1/$2/$3.png break;
        proxy_pass http://115.x.x.x:20008;


   }

   location /tile/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:20008;


        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  60m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;
    }
    ...
```

In this configuration, all requests seem to get redirected to the proxied server, but images are ultimately served. In addition, the error log contains these lines:

```
2013/09/10 09:44:11 [error] 564#0: *138 open() "/etc/nginx/html/tile/SteveCountryVic/13/7399/5027.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 118.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET /tile/SteveCountryVic/13/7399/5027.png?updated=15 HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.org"
```

If instead of using `proxy_redirect`, I use `rewrite` and `proxy_pass`:

```
        rewrite ^.*/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+).*$ /$1/$2/$3.png break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5005;
```

Then now I actually see the 404 messages in the browser (ie, they don't get intercepted).

My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Why on earth is nginx looking for files in /etc/nginx/html/...?
3. Is there a way to get even more logging information (specifically, to better understand proxy_redirect)?

Comment: Sigh, I think I've found it. The local server is actually returning code 200 even when it can't find an image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The alternative version, using `rewrite` and `proxy_pass` behaved perfectly - the problem was the other server returning 200's instead of 404's. So for completeness, here is the working config:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost;
   error_log  /tmp/nginx.error.log notice;
   access_log   /tmp/nginx.access.log;
   location /tile/SteveCountryVic/ {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^.*/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+.*)$ /$1/$2/$3 break;

        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 = @dynamiccycletour;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5005;
  }

   location @dynamiccycletour {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+.*)$ /tile/SteveCountryVic/$1/$2/$3 break;
        proxy_pass http://115.x.x.x:20008;

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

first thing you haven't set your `root` - directive correctly -> thats why you get a 404 -> thats why all requests are redirected to your @dynamiccycletour (openstreetmap?)

btw, whats the difference between /tile/ and /tile/SteveCountryVic/ ?

so we need a little cleanup here first:

```
server {
   ....
   # define where to find files 
   # be sure to have it like /path/to/tile
   root /path/to/tiles/;


   location /tile/SteveCountryVic/ {

       # if file not found -> remote server
       try_files $uri @dynamiccycletour

        rewrite_log on;        
        # this should cover /1/2/3.png. no?
        rewrite /tile/SteveCountryVic/(.*).png$ /$1.png break;

        # i'm not sure this will match due the the rewrite
        proxy_redirect /tile/SteveCountryVic/ http://localhost:5005/;


   location @dynamiccycletour {
        rewrite_log on;

        # this should cover /1/2/3.png. no?
        rewrite /tile/SteveCountryVic/(.*).png$ /$1.png break;
        proxy_pass http://115.x.x.x:20008;


   }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks - useful comments. The extra "/tile/" rule is for other map styles which are rendered on this server (I left this unnecessary detail out). In this instance though, I don't really want a "root" - for most requests, there isn't a directory that I want to map onto exactly - they need to go through a separate server (either the local one on port 5005, or the remote one on port 20008).

Comment: ah, understood. nice concept!